# unable to understand how WITH...TempTable is fetching an extra line

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `Property` which has 2 columns `PropertyRSN` and `ParentPropertyRSN`

**DATA**

```
propertyRSN | parentpropertyRSN
19          | 3
18          | 6
27          | 7
12          | 9
13          | 9
16          | 12

WITH tempTable(PLRSN, PRSN) AS (
   SELECT PropertyRSN, Property.ParentPropertyRSN 
   FROM Property 
   WHERE PropertyRSN = 16
   UNION ALL
   SELECT nplus1.PropertyRSN, nplus1.ParentPropertyRSN 
   FROM Property as nplus1, tempTable 
   WHERE tempTable.prsn = nplus1.PropertyRSN
)
SELECT PLRSN, PRSN 
FROM tempTable
```

**RESULT**

```
PLRSN | PRSN
16    | 12
12    | 9
9     | NULL
```

**Question -** I am unable to understand how the temTable query gets the row with data `9 | NULL` ?
Also I am unable to understand how is it possible to use TemTable within the brackets ?

=====================================================================

```
create table property (propertyRSN int, ParentPropertyRSN int);
Insert into property (propertyRSN, ParentPropertyRSN) values (19,3);
Insert into property (propertyRSN, ParentPropertyRSN) values (18,6);
Insert into property (propertyRSN, ParentPropertyRSN) values (27,7);
Insert into property (propertyRSN, ParentPropertyRSN) values (12,9);
Insert into property (propertyRSN, ParentPropertyRSN) values (13,9);
Insert into property (propertyRSN, ParentPropertyRSN) values (16,12);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CTE happens to be a *recursive* CTE, which I would choose to write using an explicit join:

```
WITH tempTable (PLRSN, PRSN) AS (
    SELECT PropertyRSN, Property.ParentPropertyRSN
    FROM Property
    WHERE PropertyRSN = 16

    UNION ALL

    SELECT nplus1.PropertyRSN, nplus1.ParentPropertyRSN
    FROM Property AS nplus1
    INNER JOIN tempTable t ON t.prsn = nplus1.PropertyRSN
)

SELECT PLRSN, PRSN FROM tempTable;
```

The first row with `PLRSN = 16` is coming from the base case of the recursive CTE, which appears before the `UNION ALL`.  The next two rows are coming from the two recursive steps.  While in the last iteration it is true that the `PRSN` value coming from the `tempTable` is not `NULL` (in fact it is 9), the *parent* of that record does have a `NULL` value for `PRSN`.  This is why the recursion stops at that point, because the parent has been hit.

Comment: Thanks @Tim i understood it now


- first row is from the `property` table
- second row is from the second query of the union all query where the `PRSN = 12`
- third row is  is from the second query of the union all query where the `PRSN = 9`

sinc `9` has no value for `ParentPropertyRSN`, we see `NULL`